# Firestore One time fetch vs Realtime listener in Recyclerview with filter

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have feed like the image in my app. I am getting list of some documents from firetsore collection and I am populating them in List and then use it in recycler view to show details of user.

When feed is clicked, I want to show ditrict3 and district4 data. Like below:

```
 collectionRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("male");
 collectionRef.whereIn("district", Arrays.asList("district3", "district4"))
              .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    List<FilterDetails> filterDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
                                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                        FilterDetails filterDetails = document.toObject(FilterDetails.class);
                                        filterDetailsList.add(filterDetails);
                                        getParentActivity().hideLoading();
                                    }
                                    feedItemAdapter.updateData(filterDetailsList);
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

When district1 will be clicked I will change whereEqualTo("district", "district1") and for different selection I will change.

User can change this more frequently and if I will do one time fetch then its going to cost me very much. But If I will use realtime snapshot then data will be read again and again if other users will change their info. Solutions I thought,
1) To get all the data before where clause and do district filtering on client side(app). But in this if there are 2000 users in each state. I would have to load that much data.
2) To do onetime fetch for whatever user clicks and then show them same list. I will make separate list for all fetches.

I am really confused upon this. Any insight would be helpful.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that it caches recently read documents locally, and won't charge you again if future queries are read form that cache. I'd recommend running some tests with `addSnapshotListener` and [monitoring the usage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/monitor-usage) that it generates. It may be a lot less tan you imagined, and at the very least you'll have more concrete data to validate/dispel your concerns.

If you're worried still about the pricing of Cloud Firestore, I recommend doing some back-of-a-napkin calculations of realistic scenarios. I highly recommend comparing Cloud Firestore with an alternative like the Realtime Database in that case. Most cloud-based databases come with a fairly unique pricing model, and only you can decide what combination of features and price work for your app.

Comment: Okay, maybe my realtime change would be not that much and in that case snapshot listener makes sense. But do you suggest loading data for all the districts in one snapshot and then filter my recyclerview on client app?

Comment: I recommend not loading much more data than the user is likely to see. It sounds unlikely to me that a user will read thousands of items, but only you can know that for sure.

Comment: No its unlikely. I will see what suits me in this case. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: What I am doing right now is that for seperate districts I am using simple query with whereEqualTo ="thatdistrict" and limit upto 10 and paginate... and for feed whereIn clause and limit upto 10 and paginate. Since I am using same recyclerview, I am updating data as well as listener on it for scroll. Is it right way?

Comment: Every app is different. But if this approach works for you, it's the right way. :)